# Git me sube una carpeta vacia de mi proyecto angular

Tags: angular, git, github

mi **proyecto** tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
APP
   -server (nodejs)
   -app-name (angular)
```

Estoy intentado subir mi proyecto como repositorio de **GitHub** pero solo me sube la parte de **nodejs** , es decir, el directorio llamado **/server** el de angular (**app-name**) me lo sube vacio.

Deojo una **imagen** de como se ve una vez subido:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede observar no es ni **linkeable** ese directorio.

Y cuando le hago un **clone** para ver que se ha guardado solo es una carpeta **vacio** .

¿Hay algun tipo de problema al subir **angular** a **GitHub**?

--

Este es mi `.gitignore`:

```
# See http://help.github.com/ignore-files/ for more about ignoring files.

# compiled output
/dist
/tmp
/out-tsc
# Only exists if Bazel was run
/bazel-out

# dependencies
/node_modules

# profiling files
chrome-profiler-events.json
speed-measure-plugin.json

# IDEs and editors
/.idea
.project
.classpath
.c9/
*.launch
.settings/
*.sublime-workspace

# IDE - VSCode
.vscode/*
!.vscode/settings.json
!.vscode/tasks.json
!.vscode/launch.json
!.vscode/extensions.json
.history/*

# misc
/.sass-cache
/connect.lock
/coverage
/libpeerconnection.log
npm-debug.log
yarn-error.log
testem.log
/typings

# System Files
.DS_Store
Thumbs.db
```

Esta como venia por defecto **no he tocado nada aqui**

Dentro del proyecto sigo los siquientes pasos:

1- `git init` 
2- `git add .` porque me interesa todo 
3- `git commit -m "comentario"`

En este momento me salta el siguiente error :

```
Changes not staged for commit:
        modified:   app-user-crud (modified content, untracked content)

no changes added to commit
```

---

He seguido esto : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50167969/how-to-fix-modified-content-untracked-content-in-git

y al volver hacer `git add nombreFichero`

me sale esto por la consola :

`warning: adding embedded git repository: app-user-crud
hint: You've added another git repository inside your current repository.
hint: Clones of the outer repository will not contain the contents of
hint: the embedded repository and will not know how to obtain it.
hint: If you meant to add a submodule, use:
hint: 
hint:   git submodule add <url> app-user-crud
hint: 
hint: If you added this path by mistake, you can remove it from the
hint: index with:
hint: 
hint:   git rm --cached app-user-crud
hint: 
hint: See "git help submodule" for more information.`

Comment: Hola, ¿tendrás algo configurado en el `.gitignore`?, cuesta saber cuál es el problema con tan pocos datos. Tal vez no hayas realizado el `commit` o te falte hacer un `git add .`

Comment: Es muy raro esto, nunca me ha pasado. He hecho todo esos pasos. De hecho he borrado y creado un repositorio de muchas maneras para ver si hay algo raro, pero no. Hago lo que siempre hago al subir repositorios

Comment: ¿Con `git status` te marca los ficheros como añadidos?

Comment: Mirad el error que me dice ahora al intentar hacer un `commit`

Comment: Ese error parece que dice que no has hecho el `add` correctamente. Mira a ver si lo puedes hacer por cada archivo. También, muestranos que te da de resultado `git status`.

Comment: Por archivo no lo podria hacer porque son muchisimos, es un proyecto de angular.

Comment: Cuando hago `git status` me sale el mismo error que puesto al **final** de la pregunta

Comment: ¿Y `git add app-user-crud`? Lo que te sale no es un error, solo te dice que esa carpeta ha cambiado, pero no está marcada para el commit, es decir, la ignorará. O `git add app-user-crud/*`

Comment: Claro, no es un error, simplemente la ignora, pero la pregunta es por que ? si no toque nada

Comment: Podrias probar utilizando git add --all en vez de git add .

Comment: El error me esta dando ahora cuando commiteo

Comment: Tienes mal escrito `ocmmit`. Es `commit`. Edita la pregunta y arreglalo. También te sugiero que si el problema persiste, que uses http://gitignore.io para generar nuevamente tu gitignore y lo reemplaces por el resultado de esto para asegurarte de que tengas bien el gitignore, e intentes nuevamente subirlo todo desde el principio.

Comment: El error es claro, tu carpeta `app-user-crud` ya es parte de otro repositorio. Es decir, debes tener un repositorio inicializado en dicha carpeta. Verifica que dentro de esa carpeta tienes una carpeta `.git`, elimina dicha carpeta (`.git`) y vuelve a realizar el `git add .` y luego el `commit`. Comenta los resultados. Saludos

Comment: Efectivamente @MauricioContreras tenias razon, habia un `.git` dentro. La he borrado y he commiteado todo, perfecto. Solucionado. Muchas gracias a todos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error dice que estás añadiendo un repositorio dentro de otro:

```
warning: adding embedded git repository: app-user-crud
hint: You've added another git repository inside your current repository.
```

Mira en tu carpeta `app-user-crud` seguramente haya una carpeta oculta llamada `.git`, borra esa carpeta y prueba de nuevo.

Comment: Gracias a todos, te doy la solucion correcta a ti, pero quiero que sepan que todos aportaron la solucion

Answer (score 1):

Efectivamente tal y como se comenta estás poniendo bajo git elementos que ya están bajo git, por lo que hay duplicidad de repositorio.

Tal y como te están comentando, comprueba que en la carpeta `app-user-crud` no existe una carpetita llamada .git que es lo que hace que tengas el repositorio duplicado, y asegurate bien de que esta carpeta no esté oculta.

Comment: Muchas gracias Daniel